# How to read body from POST request

Tags: c++, http, http-post, poco-libraries

I am using the [poco c++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) , especially the [HTTPServer](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html) from poco and I am already able to receive GET requests. (i followed [this](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf) tutorial from page 24+). But i cannot figure out how to handle POST request, in particular, how can i read the request body out from the POST request with poco? From the Documentation of the class [HttpServerRequest](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.HTTPServerRequest.html) i read that the method `stream` can be used for this:

```
virtual std::istream & stream() = 0;
Returns the input stream for reading the request body.
```

okay, in my code i want to call this method like:

```
 std::istream& istr = request.stream();
```

but i am getting the error:

`error: passing 'const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest' as 'this' argument of 'virtual std::istream& Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest::stream()' discards qualifiers`

what's wrong with my method call here?
Can anybody help? or provide an example?

kind regards

Comment: The problem is that you declared your `request` object as `const`, and that means you can only call methods also declared `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, because you stripped out the relevant part of the code, but the problem seems to occur because your **request**-object is declared as **const**. HTTPServerRequest::stream() is not declared const and therefore you're not allowed to call this method from a const-object.

So check out the following: where do you call the method HTTPServerRequest::stream()? Where does the request-object come from in this place? Is it declared to be constant (e.g. passed as a const function parameter)? Does it have to be declared constant in this place?

Greetings

Comment: Thank you, this exactly was the problem. The error message is difficult to understand, at least for c++ newcomers. :)